# NSCollectionView, NSCollectionViewItem, & MVC

Tags: swift, gesture-recognition, nscollectionview

Hi I'm going to add a double click gesture recognizer for items in a collection view. I have a didSelect() delegate in the collection view and I could add it there, or put it in the overridden NSCollectionViewItem class for my items. I'm trying to follow the MVC pattern but I'm not sure what makes the most sense here. I'm making a distinction between a single click on a collection view item which is normally handled by didselect() and a double click on that same item. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to add the double click gesture recognizer to selected items only? Which object will handle the double click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given this matter some more thought and along with Willeke's comment it seems to make sense to add the gesture recognizer in the item class since each item will have it. I will likely put the selector function in the collection view's viewcontroller since that is probably the class that should handle and propagate any changes in the views. Thanks Willeke for helping me clarify and think about what to do here!